# Problema para mostrar variables JSP en los alert() de javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, aplicación-web, servlets

Estoy probando mensajes de alerta en mi pagina web, estoy recogiendo valores pasados por el session y mostrandolos en un alert.

En esta primera parte obtengo los valores , lo comprobe y se recojen perfectamente

```
<%
String registro= (String)session.getAttribute("registro");
String permisos= (String)session.getAttribute("permisos"); 
Integer estado= (Integer)session.getAttribute("estado");
String nombre= (String)session.getAttribute("nombre");
String clave=(String)session.getAttribute("clave");
%>
```

Ahora con este codigo hago que se muestre el mensaje ni bien se carga la pagina

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-black sidebar-mini" style="height: auto; 
min-height: 100%; overflow-y:auto; " onload="permisosMenu()">
```

Aqui el codigo javascript, es bastante simple

```
<script >
//esto es JavaScript 
  function permisosMenu() {
      var cadena = <%=permisos%>;
  alert(cadena);
}
</script>
```

Y cuando ejecuto me muestra este mensaje (el cual es correcto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL PROBLEMA

Cuando trato de pasar otro valor que no sea esa variable como por ejemplo el "registro"

```
<script >
//esto es JavaScript 
  function permisosMenu() {
      var cadena = <%=registro%>;
  alert(cadena);
}
</script>
```

Me sale el siguiente error por consola (Ojo si llega a obtener el valor del registro que seria "admin" , pero no lo bota por el alert )

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe cual es mi error ?

Comment: metelo entre comillas simples `'<%=permisos%>;'` para que lo lea como string

Answer (score 1):

Lo que me sorprende es que no te da error con permisos.

El error que te genera se debe al comportamiento basico de javascript, aqui tienes unos ejemplos:

```
 var dato = 2;
```

Ninguna variable puede ser nombrada con un numero al principio, por lo tanto `2` se asigna como valor numero de la variable `dato`

```
var dato = "Lorem Ipsum";
```

Esta entre comillas por lo tanto eso es puro texto el valor de `dato` es simplemente lo que esta entre esas comillas

```
var dato =  algo;
```

No va entre comillas, por lo tanto no es texto, no empieza por numero? no es un valor numerico entonces, por lo tanto es otra variable u objeto

---

**Explicacion**
El problema en tu caso se debe a esta ultima intepretacion,
 a la hora de cargar la pagina el codigo queda tal que asi:

```
var cadena = admin;
```

Por lo tanto a la hora de declarar la variable `cadena` primero intenta averiguar que variable u objeto es `admin`, pero tal como te indica la consola; admin no existe.

---

**Solucion:**
Para que te lo interprete como puro texto en JavaScript simplemente tienes que escribirlo entre comillas:

```
var cadena ="\"" +  <%=registro%> + "\"";
```

O

```
var cadena ='"' +  <%=registro%> + '"';
```

Comment: Ninguna de las dos formas me funciono.
Aclaro que tampoco se porque funciona con "permisos"

Comment: @angelo1793 Te sigo escribiendo admin a secas¿

Comment: ya encontré la solución , era ponerlo entre comillas simples ' ' como me lo señalo un usuario, aun asi "permisos" sigue funcionando si esas comillas :)

Answer (score 0):

La solución como me lo comento el usuario srJJ , es poner las comillas entre las variables para convertirla en string

```
<script >
//esto es JavaScript 
  function permisosMenu() {
      var cadena = '<%=registro%>';
  alert(cadena);
}
</script>
```

Por otro lado , muy aparte de estar resuelto el problema, sigue la incógnita de que la variable "permisos" no necesite de las comillas para ser reconocida.